# react input field for text, after rerender the component, the input still hold the old value

Tags: reactjs, dom

I face one problem that in React, after I use this.forceUpdate(), the component DOM do update, but the DOM(input) still hold the old value. Like in the pictures, at first I add four rows of input, and take a notice on the number on each num, then I delete the first row, the DOM should keep the last three rows(2,3,4), but the result is that the component keep the first three rows(1,2,3).

And I inspect the page, find the component do delete the first row(the row with number 1), but the DOM still display the first three rows, just like I delete the fourth row.

And one can tell me the reason? Thank you!

[Modal with four rows of input before delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTqfb.png)

[Modal with three rows of input after delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdmkG.png)

[detail explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bunqM.png)

```
import React  from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal'


export default class AddAccountModal extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newAccount: [{source: '', url: '', name: ''}],
    }

    this.getState = this.getState.bind(this);
    this.addMoreAccount = this.addMoreAccount.bind(this);
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.deleteAccount = this.deleteAccount.bind(this);
  }


  getState(){
    return this.state
  }

  updateInputValue(event){
    this.state.newAccount[event.target.id][event.target.name] = event.target.value
  }

  deleteAccount(event){
    console.log(event.target.id)
    this.state.newAccount.splice(event.target.id,1)
    console.log(this.state.newAccount)
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  addMoreAccount(){
    this.state.newAccount.push({source: '', url: '', name: ''})
    console.log(this.getState()['newAccount'])
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Modal {...this.props}
             bsSize="large"
             aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
            Add New Account
            <Button className="pull-right" onClick={this.props.hideModal}>X</Button>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="row">
            <table className="table table-striped">
              <thead><th>Account source</th><th>Account URL</th><th>Account name</th><th>Delete</th></thead>
              <tbody>
                {
                  this.state.newAccount.map(
                    (account,index)=>{return <tr>
                      {/*<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='source' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.source}/></td>*/}
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='source' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} ref={(input)=>{account.source=input}}/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='url' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.url}/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.name}/></td>
                      <td><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" id={index} onClick={this.deleteAccount}></i></td>
                    </tr>})
                }
                <tr><td></td><td><button onClick={ this.addMoreAccount }>+</button></td><td></td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.hideModal}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be performing direct operations on the state.

If you are using `setState` properly there is no need for you to call `forceUpdate`, `setState` itself will call for a rerender of the app.

I will advise you to `bind` the `index` to the `deleteAccount` function instead of setting and retrieving an id from the event.

In order to properly mutate an state you need can clone the state variable in a temporary array and change that and then set the state like

```
deleteAccount(id){
    var newAccount = [...this.state.newAccount];
    newAccount.splice(id,1);
    this.setState({newAccount}, () => {console.log(this.state.newAccount)});
  }
```

I am assuming that the extra `}` in your map function after

```
 <td><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" id={index} onClick={this.deleteAccount}></i></td>
                </tr>}    <------ here
```

is a typo that is not in your original code. If its there you need to remove it.

Also when you set State, it doesn't mutate immediately and hence if you want to log it immediately after you should be using a setState callback as I have used in the below code like

```
this.setState({newAccount}, () => {console.log(this.state.newAccount)});
```

Complete code should look like this

```
import React  from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal'


export default class AddAccountModal extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newAccount: [{source: '', url: '', name: ''}],
    }

    this.getState = this.getState.bind(this);
    this.addMoreAccount = this.addMoreAccount.bind(this);
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.deleteAccount = this.deleteAccount.bind(this);
  }


  getState(){
    return this.state
  }

  updateInputValue(event){
    var newAccount = [...this.state.newAccount];
    newAccount[event.target.id][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({newAccount});
  }

  deleteAccount(id){
    var newAccount = [...this.state.newAccount];
    newAccount.splice(id,1);
    this.setState({newAccount}, () => {console.log(this.state.newAccount)});
  } 

  addMoreAccount(){
    var newAccount = [...this.state.newAccount];
    newAccount.push({source: '', url: '', name: ''})
    this.setState({newAccount}, () => {console.log(this.state.newAccount)})

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Modal {...this.props}
             bsSize="large"
             aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
            Add New Account
            <Button className="pull-right" onClick={this.props.hideModal}>X</Button>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="row">
            <table className="table table-striped">
              <thead><th>Account source</th><th>Account URL</th><th>Account name</th><th>Delete</th></thead>
              <tbody>
                {
                  this.state.newAccount.map(
                    (account,index)=>{return <tr>
                      {/*<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='source' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.source}/></td>*/}
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='source' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} ref={(input, index)=>{account.source=input}}/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='url' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.url}/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id={index} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.name}/></td>
                      <td><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" id={index} onClick={this.deleteAccount.bind(this, index)}></i></td>
                    </tr>)
                }
                <tr><td></td><td><button onClick={ this.addMoreAccount }>+</button></td><td></td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.hideModal}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: @Khatri thanks for your welcome reply, khatri. Thanks the advice about use setState properly to rerender the compoment.  But the proplem I post is still existed, the last item seems deleted.

Comment: can you confirm the output that you get when you do console.log(id, newAccount) in deleteAccount functin after `newAccount.splice(id,1);` statement

Comment: @Khatri yes, I'm sure that, after I remove the first row, but the last row disappear. And the log info indicate the first row is removed.

Comment: how did account.url get its value

Comment: I assign them, they are inputs for text, I just type value

Comment: can you just attach the result of console.log(this.state.newAccount) in deleteAccount, so that I can figure out something else

Comment: see attachment please, a add one more picture.  I add for rows ,then delete the first row.    If you are very interested in this, I think you can set it a very simple react page, and play it , will be more convenient and quick.   see you  later

Comment: Hello, Khatri, I found the reason, I should add 'value=' for every input,like this:  <input type="text" className="form-control" name='url' id={account.id} value={account.url} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.url}/>

Comment: Sorry I didn't get time to work on the problem, although I suspected that the value is being changed and not the Dom, good you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

everyone, I make a stupid mistake, I should add "value=" for each input. Though I still don't know how adding "value=" in the input make it.

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" name='url' id={account.id} value={account.url} onChange={this.updateInputValue} defaultValue={account.url}/>
```